# perl split a line on the 3rd ] with regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have this line:
    `[Fri Oct  5 09:11 2012] 0.005 [ext2/1/rel 322 (0,50)] [abc] I'm Sure [he/she] is leading CORN @types (countyfair)`

How do i split it from the **3rd ]** and have 2 parts:

```
[Fri Oct  5 09:11 2012] 0.005 [ext2/1/rel 322 (0,50)] [abc]
```

and

```
I'm Sure [he/she] is leading CORN @types (countyfair)
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed to be the **last** `]` on that line?

Comment: @m.buettner-  not its not guaranted . see update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one skips three `]`s:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  if (my ($p1, $p2) = (/([^]]+][^]]+][^]]+])\s*(.*)/)) {
    print "$p1 : $p2\n";
  }
}
```

Using an array:

```
my @a; 
while (<>) {
  if (@a = (/([^]]+][^]]+][^]]+])\s*(.*)/)) {
    print join(",", @a), "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: thks 4 quick answer.Is it possible to use split? I am working with an array.

Comment: @mamesaye, using split complicates this thing and you need some temporary arrays

Comment: I was able to move the first solution in the right section of my script.saved me some hours,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A look-behind for three strings each terminated by `]` will do the trick. You didn't mention what you wanted to do with the whitespace after the third `]` so I've left it there.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = q{[Fri Oct 5 09:11 2012] 0.005 [ext2/1/rel 322 (0,50)] [abc] I'm Sure [he/she] is leading CORN @types (countyfair)};
my @pair = split /(?:[^]]*\]){3}\K/, $s;

print "$_\n" for @pair;
```

**output**

```
[Fri Oct 5 09:11 2012] 0.005 [ext2/1/rel 322 (0,50)] [abc]
 I'm Sure [he/she] is leading CORN @types (countyfair)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got interested in a generic function, so here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = q{[Fri Oct 5 09:11 2012] 0.005 [ext2/1/rel 322 (0,50)] [abc] I'm Sure [he/she] is leading CORN @types (countyfair)};  #'# fix highlight

my ($first, $second) = split_after_nth( qr/]/, $str, 3 );
$second =~ s/^\s*//;  #/# fix highlight
print "$first\n$second\n";

sub split_after_nth {
  my ($qr, $str, $num) = @_;
  my @parts = split /($qr)/, $str, ++$num;
  my $second = pop @parts;
  my $first = join '', @parts;
  return ($first, $second);
}
```